# (Overwriting?) Issue With Pushing Search Results To Array

Tags: javascript, jquery

For some reason the following filter functionality I wrote is not appending to my results array properly. It seems to insert X occurrences of the last result object rather than the X number of result objects of the filter matches. Replacing "results.push(result)" in both places with "console.log(result)" returns the proper/different X result objects in my console window. Any idea why this strange behavior is occurring?

The goal is to have a results array of X number of result objects with each result object containing pertinent values from parent/sibling objects of each matching show name (such as day & time parents and network, title, & episode siblings).

```
// simple filter used to search show names
filter: function(el, string) {
    console.clear();
    string = $.trim(string);
    var results = [];
    var result = {};
    if ( string.length ) {
        for ( var i=0; i < el.length; i++ ) {
            for ( var j=0; j < el[i]["time"].length; j++ ) {
                if ( _.isArray(el[i]["time"][j].show) ) {
                    for ( var k=0; k < el[i]["time"][j].show.length; k++ ) {
                        if ( el[i]["time"][j].show[k]["@attributes"]["name"].search(new RegExp(string, "i")) > -1 ) {
                            result.day = el[i]["@attributes"]["attr"];
                            result["time"] = el[i]["time"][j]["@attributes"].attr;
                            result.show = el[i]["time"][j].show[k]["@attributes"]["name"];
                            result.sid = el[i]["time"][j].show[k].sid;
                            result.network = el[i]["time"][j].show[k].network;
                            result["title"] = el[i]["time"][j].show[k]["title"];
                            result.ep = el[i]["time"][j].show[k].ep;
                            result["link"] = el[i]["time"][j].show[k]["link"];
                            results.push(result);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if ( el[i]["time"][j].show["@attributes"]["name"].search(new RegExp(string, "i")) > -1 ) {
                        result.day = el[i]["@attributes"]["attr"];
                        result["time"] = el[i]["time"][j]["@attributes"].attr;
                        result.show = el[i]["time"][j].show["@attributes"]["name"];
                        result.sid = el[i]["time"][j].show.sid;
                        result.network = el[i]["time"][j].show.network;
                        result["title"] = el[i]["time"][j].show["title"];
                        result.ep = el[i]["time"][j].show.ep;
                        result["link"] = el[i]["time"][j].show["link"];
                        results.push(result);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(results);
}
```

For a live demo of the issue at hand, please visit my test page [here](http://colechrzan.com/tv_rewrite). For convenience, I'm logging the large object through which the filter function is meant to iterate over to the console when the page fully loads to give an idea of the structure of that object so my filter function makes more sense to others (readers of this post).

Also here is how I'm calling the filter:

```
// filter show names for user input
$(".search").children("input").keyup(function() {
    var str = $(this).val();
    ctv.filter(ctv.xml.DAY, str);
});
```

Comment: Try adding `var result;` before starting to set the properties of the result, (after the if that checks the presence of the string)

Comment: Doesn't change anything. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, seems like a somewhat silly oversight on my part. "Clearing the result var (ie. `result = {};`) just before beginning to set the attributes did the trick. Thanks for making me think around that area koala_dev. :)